# How to control the order in which the markup for fields appears in the outputted html source for content?

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to control (as in change) the order in which the fields appear in the html markup?

On admin page for a content type `admin/structure/types/manage/<content type>/fields` and in the Manage Fields tab, the fields can be dragged and re-ordered in the list.

However, looking at the outputted html source, the order does not change according to the order in this list. Is it supposed to? (I'd like to think it does).

I also looked at [field_weight](https://drupal.org/project/field_weight) to control the order of the output but it unclear in what the author(s) of this module mean by 'weight'. Trying this module didn't appear to change the order in the resultant html source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change tho order these fields are displayed from Manage Display `(admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT TYPE/display)`. Edit the weight there and the fields should be displayed in the selected order on the node view page.

**Edit**: In the fields screen `(admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT TYPE/fields)` the weight is used for displaying the form fields in the edit/add content type form.

Comment: Yes - I see now - thank you! +1 and Accepted. I should add some things to support the answer: 1) the ordering I needed is done in admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT TYPE/display (the 'Manage display' tab). Curiously, the 'Manage fields' tab ( admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT TYPE/fields ) does not maintain the same order defined in 'Manage display' (not sure why - it doesn't matter for me, but comments?) 2) you can also see the weights as numeric values by selecting 'show row weights' on the right 3) this functionality is built in, field_weights provides per node granularity of control.

Comment: Just to add @therobyouknow the ordering on the Manage Fields screen affects the node editing form :)

Comment: Ahh OK I see yes, thank you +1. Well that's good flexibility because I guess the order in which the data is entered may need to be different from how it is displayed (differing usability needs for data entry and display). Great thanks. :)